# Issue while uploading app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios

I uploaded my app on iTunes connect. But they rejected my app and they are telling that "The seller and company name associated with the app don't reflect the name". Can anyone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this http://www.brynbodayle.com/changing-app-store-seller-name/

Answer (score 0):

**Contact Apple**

The easiest way to change your seller name is to contact Apple developer support. If there is a typo or inaccuracy in your seller name they should be willing to change it. Back before I released Card Share my individual account had a seller name for a fictitious entity that did not exist. Since it wasn’t my legal name, Apple support was willing to make the name change. I contacted support and within 24 hours my seller name was changed and updated in the App Store. Here is the email to contact Apple about seller name changes and other iTunes related support: itunesconnect@apple.com

**New Account + App Transfer**

Outside of contacting Apple, there is a more hands-on approach. Before WWDC in 2013, Apple announced the ability to transfer apps between developer accounts. By creating a new developer account with a new name and transferring your apps to that account, you can effectively change your seller name. There are a few restrictions on apps that can be transferred.